# Magento 2.4 Error on front and admin panel No mapping found for position_category

Tags: magento2

I get error when I open admin panel of Magento 2.4

```
BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_103] in order to sort on
```

I tried `bin/magento indexer:reindex` and `bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`
but it doesn't help

Comment: This is not enough for anybody to help you.

Comment: Plz share website link or share more details.

Comment: make sure you have elsticsearch up and running